# jQuery form plugin success callback is not executing

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I am not sure why the jQuery form plugin success callback function  is not executing.  Why is the callback not executing and how do I execute the callback?

code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var insertOptions =
        { 
            // other available options: 
            url:       'manage_livestock/insert_livestock',
            type:      'post',
            dataType:  'json', 
            clearForm: true,
            //resetForm: true 

            // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
            timeout:   3000,

            success: showResponse
        };

        $("#livestock").ajaxForm(insertOptions);
    });  

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)
    {
        alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + 
            '\n\nSuccess!'); 
    }
</script>
```

-Rich

Comment: Are you sure that `200` http code is returned?

Comment: Did you try loading the page in firefox with firebug? Maybe zerkms is right and you`re not getting a 200 ok status.

Comment: @zerkms @Elad Lachmi I am receiving a 200 ok status, I verified it in firebug.  The page that is 200 ok status returns: Values have been inserted successfully!

Comment: @dottedquad: is the response a valid json?

Comment: I changed the datatype to html.  Now it works.  I will have to wait 8 hours in order to answer my own question.

Comment: @dottedquad: to be clear - you followed my advice about valid json ;-P Is not it fair to give the checkmark to me? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

As I proposed in the comments - the response should be a valid `json`, otherwise you could change the type to `html`.